# OffsetDateTime toString() return different format date string

Tags: java, date

I have date in this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`, but while i'm parsing this using `OffsetDateTime.parse(date);` it returns the string by elimination `seconds`

**Logic :** Get the day from date, if it is `Saturday` or `Sunday` change day to monday and return the date String

```
String date = "2018-12-30T06:00:00Z";

System.out.println(date);

try {
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);

    System.out.println(dateTime);           //2018-12-30T06:00Z

    DayOfWeek day = dateTime.getDayOfWeek();
    // check if price change  date is Sunday or Saturday and change it to Monday
    if (day.equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) || day.equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)) {

        String finalDateTime = dateTime.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)).toString();
         System.out.println(finalDateTime);      //2018-12-31T06:00Z
    }else {
        System.out.println(date);
    }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
```

I need to return string as same input format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`

Comment: Why don't you use LocalDateTime?

Comment: honestly i'm not good at java date time, but i have an offset in String right `Z`?

Comment: Don't use `toString()`, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(dateTime.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)))`

Comment: That works thank you @ernest_k

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As per [`OffsetDateTime.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--) method javadoc the shortest possible format for the value is used while omitted parts are implied to be zero. The shortest possible format for `2018-12-30T06:00:00Z` is `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXXXX` so the seconds and nanos are skipped:

> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXXXX
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXXX
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSXXXXX
>
> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

If you need a precise format use a `DateTimeFormatter` instance with specific pattern to output the date:

```
String date = "2018-12-30T06:00:00Z";
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
System.out.println(fmt.format(dt));
```